# Searching Databases

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2000 and want to write a simple query to return the name of all databases not containing `equipmentpropertyid` number above 905 in the `defs_equipmentpropertytable`. We have a hundred or more active databases all containing the same tables. Unfortunately, the `defs_equipmentpropertytable` is up-to-date in most of the databases, but not all. I need to figure out which databases need to have that particular table updated. We have a tool that will search all the databases, I just need the correct syntax for the query.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone may mention the undocumented stored procedure sp_msforeachdb, which can do this. However, I suggest you write a query to generate the SQL yourself, then run it. Something like this should work:

```
declare @query nvarchar(400);
set @query = N'
select top 1 ''Found in '' + %%% as r
from $$$.dbo.defs_equipmentpropertytable
where equipmentpropertyid > 905
go
';
select replace(replace(@query,'$$$',quotename(name)),'%%%',quotename(name,''''))
from master..sysdatabases
```

Run this, then copy the result back to a query window and execute the result. You can also filter out any databases you don't want.

I strongly suggest this instead of sp_MSforeachdb, because this gives you the chance to inspect your SQL before you run it, and that's a good habit for avoiding SQL injection, not to mention bad mistakes.

**I had it backwards. Does this work?**

```
declare @query nvarchar(400);
set @query = N'
if not exists (
  select *
  from $$$.dbo.defs_equipmentpropertytable
  where equipmentpropertyid > 905
) select %%% + 'is not up to date' as r
go
';
select replace(replace(@query,'$$$',quotename(name)),'%%%',quotename(name,''''))
from master..sysdatabases
```

Comment: This works to provide a list of databases that are up to date.  I need the databases that are not up to date...the ones I need to fix.  I have a tool to search across all databases, I just need the correct syntax...example: if not exists (select * from defs_equipmentpropertytable where equipmentpropertyid > 905) ... this doesn't work.

Comment: I guess I had it backwards. Does the second query create the right queries to run?

Answer (score 0):

This query should do what you need, if the tool does all of the searching for you; it will return the database name if the MAX propertyid <=905.

```
SELECT DB_NAME() as DatabaseName
FROM dbo.defs_equipmentpropertytable
HAVING MAX(equipmentpropertyid) <= 905
```

Hopefully, that gets what you need.  If your database crawling tool doesn't work with this, you can certainly use the method Steve provided.